# How to generate eliot tasks for eliottree render_tasks?

Tags: python, logging

How do you generate the `tasks` argument for the `render_tasks` function (mentioned in the [eliottree docs](https://github.com/jonathanj/eliottree#usage-from-python)?)

```
import json, sys
from eliottree import tasks_from_iterable, render_tasks
# Or `codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout).write` on Python 2.
render_tasks(sys.stdout.write, tasks, colorize=True)
```

I presume `tasks_from_iterable` should be used somehow, but what iterable does it consume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. Instead `to_file` you have to use `add_destination` with a function object that will receive a `message` when e.g. `Message.log()` is called:

```
from sys import stdout
from codecs import getwriter
from eliottree import tasks_from_iterable, render_tasks
from eliot import add_destination

add_destination(render_stdout)

def render_stdout(message):
    render_tasks(getwriter('utf-8')(stdout).write, tasks_from_iterable([message]), colorize=True, human_readable=True)
```

The whole tree is not rendered here, only one branch at a time, but that's how you generate eliot tasks.